# How to represent this table?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have the following table :

[image: screenshot of a table]

I would like to represent this table in Python so I'll be able to run on each key and search for specific string, if I have a much, return the `keyName`.

for example:

```
str = "c"
if str == [searching all values inside the table]:
    return keyName
```

What will be the best option for me?

Comment: Im not python expert, but I think you need `pandas` lib, see e.g which best suits to your qs: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions.html

Comment: What does "be able to run on each key" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with dictionary in python:

```
dictionary_table = {'test1':['a','b','c','d'],'test2':['e','f','g','h'],'test3':['i','j','k','l']}
search_str = "c"
key = [k for k,v in dictionary_table.items() if search_str in v]
print key
```

search "c" in the dictionary values, and get its key:

```
['test1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dict of list.
That way you can iterate over the keys and search for your value:

```
for key, values in ket_value_map.iteritems():
    if searched_value in values:
        return key
```

Hope I understood you